# React js state value late update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

set the state value in Useeffect function and  want to use that value after 5 lines in filter function but the state show the empty value means it update the state late how to solve this error

Comment: please provide some code snippet to understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

setState is an asynchronous function. Let's take this example
 `const [testState, setTestState] = useState()`

and in a useEffect, if you call lets say `setTestState('1234')` and the very next line you try to log it `console.log(testState)` - this wont log `'123'` as the `setTestState` is asynchronous, which is happening in your case.

Solution -

Put the filter function in a different `useEffect` and pass the state in the dependency array